# How to dissmiss keyboard in MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using MFMailComposeViewController to compose email for my iPhone app. How could I dismiss keyboard after entering 'toRecipients'?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
UIWindow* keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView* firstResponder = [keyWindow performSelector:@selector(firstResponder)];
[firstResponder resignFirstResponder];
```

But Also Remember.

**Important:** The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. Apple might reject your app for it. [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Possible Duplicate ***Question & Answer*** http://stackoverflow.com/q/4872565/1059705